# Change properties of tomcat on-the-fly

Tags: tomcat, configuration, properties

When we make some changes to `.properties` file in tomcat, the server should be restarted.

The question is why ?

What should I do if I want to make on-the-fly changes to tomcat server's properties ( ie without restarting tomcat server ) ?

Comment: If it's an on-the-fly change, I would expect it being effective immediately. Or do you want your changes to apply after the next (manual) Tomcat restart?

Comment: Can you be more specific which .properties file are you changing, is this catalina.properties or some .properties file for your webapp?

Comment: @f_puras There should not be need of restarting server. Let's assume logging.properties.

Comment: Have you checked [Recognizing properties file changes without restarting Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643044)?

Comment: @f_puras yes, but it is not satisfactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `reloadable` attribute of Tomcat's [Context](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) element to false, the server will not restart when it finds configuration changes while running.

Yet this applies only to `/WEB-INF/classes` and `/WEB-INF/lib`, so it would be helpful if you specified which properties file you want to change, as suggested in the comments.