# How to read properties file of application context scope without restarting server if any modification is done

Tags: spring, tomcat7

I'm using tomcat server i've requirement that in some condition we modify the properties file value (which is in application context scope), and then i've to read that modified value of properties file without restarting the server.Is there any way to do this?
Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm using spring xml configuration file to load the .properties file (<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:persistence/datasource.properties, 
      classpath:persistence/hibernate.properties" 
 ignore-unresolvable="false" ignore-resource-not-found="true" /> in spring configuration xml file) even though changes reflected in .properties it is not picking the new changed value, its still fetching old value. I'm using this new changed value in @Scheduled annotaion (i.e @Scheduled(cron="${cron.expression}") for cron job

Comment: Please give me the solution for if .properties is changed/modified means it should automatically reload without restarting the server. Thanks

Comment: @BalusC any sollution for this or any alternative ways?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643044/recognizing-properties-file-changes-without-restarting-tomcat

Comment: @kamirru thanq for the reply, i referred the link you given and followed the same steps for the problem, its reading updated file but after refreshing the application context m getting "MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed" and "JpaSystemException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]" any solution for this

Comment: Sorry, never heard of it. You must do researche by your won :)

Comment: @kamirru, thanx for the reply, i'll check and post the solution for this once i come to know.